# Symfony 5 vich_upload delete file not working

Tags: symfony, delete-file, lifecycle, symfony5, vichuploaderbundle

I have got an issue with Vich_upload on symfony 5, I can't delete the file with a normal crud. 
 I check on a lot forum and git issue, I use the lifecycle event configuration in the documentation but cannot solve the issue.
i can upload and edite the file but not delete it.
The file is not delete to the database and not delete to the save folder.
Entity image.php

```
        /**
             * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
             * @Assert\Length(min = 3, max = 255, minMessage = "Le nom de l'image doit être minimum égale à {{ limit }} caractères.", maxMessage = "Le nom de l'image doit être inférieur à {{ limit }} caractères.")
             */
            private $image_label;
        **
             * @Vich\UploadableField(mapping="product_image", fileNameProperty="image_label")
             * @var File|null
             */
            private $image_file;
        /**
             * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
             */
            private $updated_at;
    /**
         * @return File|null
         */
        public function getImageFile(): ?File
        {
            return $this->image_file;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param File $image_file
         * @return Image
         */
        public function setImageFile(File $image_file): Image
        {
            $this->image_file = $image_file;
    
            if ($this->image_file instanceof UploadedFile) {
                // It is required that at least one field changes if you are using doctrine
                // otherwise the event listeners won't be called and the file is lost
                $this->updated_at = new DateTime("now");
            }
    
            return $this;
        }
 /**
     * @return DateTimeInterface|null
     */
    public function getUpdatedAt(): ?DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->updated_at;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTimeInterface $updated_at
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setUpdatedAt(DateTimeInterface $updated_at): self
    {
        $this->updated_at = $updated_at;

        return $this;
    }
```

ImageType.php

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            /*.....*/
            ->add('image_file', VichImageType::class, [
                'required'      => false,
                'allow_delete'  => true,
                'download_link' => true,
            ])
           /*......*/
        ;
    }
```

vich_uploader.yaml

```
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

    mappings:
        product_image:
            uri_prefix: /images/products
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/images/products'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\OrignameNamer

        product_video:
            uri_prefix: /video
            upload_destination: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/video'
            namer: Vich\UploaderBundle\Naming\OrignameNamer

            inject_on_load: false
            delete_on_update: true
            delete_on_remove: true
```

ImageController.php

```
 /**
     * @Route("/{id}", name="image_delete", methods={"DELETE"})
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Image $image
     * @return Response
     */
    public function delete(Request $request, Image $image): Response
    {
        if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$image->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
            $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $entityManager->remove($image);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }

        return $this->redirectToRoute('image_index');
    }
```

_delete_form.html.twig

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path('image_delete', {'id': image.id}) }}" onsubmit="return confirm('Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir supprimer cette image ?');">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token('Supprimer' ~ image.id) }}">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-1">Supprimer</button>
</form>
```

Thank you in advance.
Best regards.

Comment: change "supprimer" in the twig form  by delete or delete in the action by "supprimer" and try

Comment: Thank for your answers just find at the same time but really thank to you for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

Big mistake on my part i translate the csrf token value="{{ csrf_token('Supprimer' ~ image.id) }}" and finally can not verify the token, my bad, sorry for the disturb.